# How to get the a URL using uri_string() codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to implement and login authentication function that check every URL when a controller is loaded like this ?

```
 //get the current URL
        $url = $this->uri->uri_string();

     if(  ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()== false )&& 
          !( in_array($url,$public_allowed_urls) ) ) {
                 redirect('users/login');
            }
```

I have also tried changing this from `AUTO`
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

Please how do you do it ..i use latest CI ?

Comment: Instead of checking URL you can check controller name and method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know what ..you will spend your time looking to make work for URI_STRING THING?

But , i have made a solution to you folks ...

get actions and controller first

like **"Weclome/Home" ,"users/login",'sell/sell','sell/index','sell/','/'**

```
   //get the current URL
    $controller= $this->uri->segment(1); // controller
    $action = $this->uri->segment(2); // action
    $url = $controller . '/' . $action; 
    //'this returns / sometimes and  also  like sell/ returned'


 if(  ($this->ion_auth->logged_in()== false )&& (in_array($url,$public_allowed_urls) ) )
 {                  
  redirect('users/login');
  }
```

done men!

Edited:

`$this->uri->segment(1);` cannot be controller name all time.To get controller name use `$this->router->class` and for method `$this->router->method`

Comment: `$this->uri->segment(1);` cannot be controller name all time.To get controller name use `$this->router->class` and for method `$this->router->method `

Comment: There may be more levels. For example when controllers are inside a directory