# How to send id to controller in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm using below code for my site, but it displayed me

> 404: Page not found.

**routes**

```
$route['class_name/function_name/(:num)'] = 'class_name/function_name/$1';
```

**Controller**.

```
 public function function_name($Id)
    {
        print_r($Id); exit;
    }
```

Comment: And from where you were getting `$Id`

Comment: don't know I am try to using the from google search. Also I have used $this->uri->segment(3), but they don't give me the number

Comment: Is the URL you are using something like http://example.com/class_name/function_name/3, or are you using a different format?

Comment: Yes. I am using example.com/class_name/function_name/3.

Comment: @Fadu This is all code of Controller?

Comment: Try to type `example.com/index.php/class_name/function_name/$id //change your names/values accordingly.` in URL.

Comment: I have wrote Rewrire rule into .htaccess to remove index.php from URL.

Comment: @splash58 Yes I know. But what is the wrong in my code. Can you please help me?

Comment: @Fadu at least, add `class class-name extends CI_Controller {`

Comment: @splash58 I have added it into controller, but I don't know how to get the id into controller.. Currently I used http://hostname/classname/?id=10 & in controller I give the id through GET method. In index function I define the function name & added the same function into the same controller

Comment: @Fadu What a version of ci ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use URI to extract the id from URL: 
Following is the link in docs : http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/uri.html

Example- [How to get the a URL using uri_string() codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170698/how-to-get-the-a-url-using-uri-string-codeigniter)

Comment: I have used $this->uri->segment(3), but they don't give me the number

Comment: I have used your link. Go through but found proper solution to me. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have create a simple one maybe it could help you out

this is my controller welcome.php fresh from codeigniter

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }

    public function test1($ID) {
        echo $ID;
    }

    public function test2($ID, $ID2) {
        var_dump($ID, $ID2);
    }

    public function test() {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

and here is my route

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';

$route['welcome/test1/(:num)'] = 'welcome/test1/$1';

$route['welcome/test/(:num)/(:num)'] = 'welcome/test/$1/$2';
```

example to access it if working

https://192.168.248.209/stackoverflow/welcome/test2/1/3
https://192.168.248.209/stackoverflow/welcome/test1/1

this one is dynamic according to your server implementation

See [Pretty Url Setup CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/urls.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I used your code in my default controller, but not worked properly. Is there any help? . Is there any setting in config file?

Comment: @Fadu, htaccess and mod_rewrite you enable it?